# pandas explode function throwing error when I have empty list in my row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

when I have empty list in my row I am getting this error:

`ValueError: columns must have matching element counts`

here is my datframe:

```
                product title                    variation_list
 Chauvet DJ GigBar Move Effect Light System       ['Black', 'White']
 Pioneer DJ DJM-S11 Professional DJ Mixer          []
 DJM-S11 Professional DJ                           []
 Pioneer DJ                                        ['black']
 dj                                                ['white','blue','red']
```

When I deleted row of empty list the error gone. How to overcome it?

here is my code:

```
df[['variation_list']] = df[['variation_list']].applymap(lambda x: eval(x, {'nan': np.nan}))

df = df.explode(['variation_list'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any() to check if list is empy. If the list is empty it will return False, otherwise True.
If list is empty, change it to None, otherwise retain the value as a non-empty list

```
df[['short_des_list']] = df[['short_des_list']].applymap(lambda x: None if any(eval(x)) == False else eval(x))
df[['variation_list']] = df[['variation_list']].applymap(lambda x: None if any(eval(x)) == False else eval(x))
df[['price_list']] = df[['price_list']].applymap(lambda x: None if any(eval(x)) == False else eval(x))
df[['main_image_list']] = df[['main_image_list']].applymap(lambda x: None if any(eval(x)) == False else eval(x))

df = df.explode(['variation_list','short_des_list','price_list','main_image_list'])
df
```

Comment: can you please explain this line of code `.applymap(lambda x: None if any(eval(x)) == False else eval(x)`

Comment: Let x be equal to the value of row in df.variation_list [ lambda x: ].  If list is empty [ if any(eval(x)) == False ], change it to [ None ], otherwise [ else ] retain the value as a non-empty list [ eval(x) ]

Comment: I am getting this error when adding multiple column `ValueError: columns must have matching element counts`. I am trying to do something like that `df[['short_des_list','variation_list','price_list','main_image_list']] = df[['short_des_list','variation_list','price_list','main_image_list']].applymap(lambda x: None if any(eval(x)) == False else eval(x))`

Comment: Try doing it one column at a time.

Comment: now getting this error `columns must have matching element counts` after using your updated answer for multiple column

Comment: Can you show the full trace back error?

Comment: see the screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Av3Ya6wm86v4juiIxsWJnhtuoY9vC7yP/view?usp=sharing